# Pass delegate / strategy vs return aggregated result to implement business logic?

Tags: oop, interface, architecture, callback, delegates

There are methods that must deal with special situations.

For example, method `Print` must deal with situations when printing was manually canceled by the user during printing (`Canceled`) or printer is out of paper (`OutOfPaper`).

There situations are not errors and not exceptions, because they are part of business logic.

I see two variants of method implementation.

Variant 1:

```
public enum PrintResult
    Ok
    Canceled
    OutOfPaper
end enum

public function Print() as PrintResult

end function
```

Method `Print` has a distinct result type `PrintResult` which contains a report of what happened during method execution.

Consumer calls method `Print`, obtains the result, analyses the result and decides what to do next.

Variant 2:

```
public Sub Print(CanceledAction as Action, OutOfPaperAction as Action)

end Sub
```

Method `Print` doesn't have a distinct result type, but behavior what to do in special situations is passed to the method by means of callbacks / delegates / interfaces.

When calling method `Print` consumer provides methods to use is special situations.

Questions:

1. Are there other variants?
2. When is it better to use each variant?

Answer (score 0):

I vote for returning a result. Passing delegates implies that method knows much more of the situation that it should.

Ideally, method should not know that some actions are even available. It just returns its state. Is there any action there to react or not it is not its bussiness.